# Bootstrap notifications?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, notifications

When creating web apps for both desktop and mobile usage, in what ways can I notify the user that e.g. a "save" operation has succeeded? 
I'm using Twitter Bootstrap and there seems to be a ton of different ways, jquery purr, growl, dismiss buttons in bootstrap and a handfull of custom notification frameworks.

What is considered standard in this matter and what frameworks are worth using for this?

ok. maybe a bit subjective but I hope there is atleast some semi standard here.

Answer (score 3):

I really like [Noty](http://needim.github.io/noty/)

But it is a really subjective question. And possibly not a question for SO.